# How is hashing done in environment in R? (for optimizing lookup performance)

Tags: r, hash, hashtable

When using a lookup by name in a list, it is possible to first turn the list into an environment with hashing. For example:

```
x <- 1:1e5
names(x) <- x
lx <- as.list(x)
elx <- list2env(lx, hash = TRUE) # takes some time

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(x[[which(x==1000)]], x[["1000"]], lx[["1000"]], get("1000", envir = elx), elx[["1000"]])
```

With the following performance gain:

```
> microbenchmark(x[[which(x==1000)]], x[["1000"]], lx[["1000"]], get("1000", envir = elx), elx[["1000"]])
Unit: nanoseconds
                     expr    min       lq       mean   median       uq     max neval cld
    x[[which(x == 1000)]] 547213 681609.5 1063382.25 720718.5 788538.5 5999776   100   b
              x[["1000"]]   6518   6829.0    7961.83   7139.0   8070.0   22659   100  a 
             lx[["1000"]]   6518   6829.0    8284.63   7140.0   8070.5   33212   100  a 
 get("1000", envir = elx)    621    931.0    2477.22   1242.0   2794.0   20175   100  a 
            elx[["1000"]]      0      1.0    1288.47    311.0   1552.0   22659   100  a
```

When looking at the help page for `list2env`:

> (for the case envir = NULL): logical indicating if the created
>   environment should use hashing, see new.env.

When looking at the help for `new.env`, it doesn't explain how the hash table is created, but it does say:

> For the performance implications of hashing or not, see
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.

So it's obvious that hashing is done, and works well (at least for the example I gave), but seeing from the Wikipedia page, it is clear there are various ways of creating hash tables. Hence, my question is: **how is the hash table created in `list2env`?**

Comment: I don't understand the downvote fot this question.

Comment: I do not either...it is kind of rude in this case with a clear question and no comment directing you to improve it. In this case, it might be worth checking in the vignette for the email address of the package author. If you point them to this post, then can answer it for the whole world to see.

Comment: This seems like the starting point of the compiled code - https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/builtin.c - look for `do_newenv` which then calls on `R_NewHashedEnv` (I think - C code is not my thing).

Comment: I keep updating, see here - https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/envir.c - search for "string hashing" - it states "*This is taken from the second edition of the "Dragon Book" by
  Aho, Ullman and Sethi.*"